# how is the output of this nested loop being calculated?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, matrix, nested-loops

Hi I have this calculation but I am failing to understand how this line `[array([1050885., 1068309., 1085733., 1103157., 1120581.])` of the output is calculated, please explain.

creating sample data:

```
#creating sample data:
data1 = pd.DataFrame({"client": ['x1', 'x2'],
                              "cat": ['Bb', 'Ee'],
                              "amt": [1000,300],
                              "time":[2, 3],
                              "group":[10, 25]})

listc = ['Aa','Bb','Cc','Dd','Ee']

val1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 2, 3],
                       'lim %': [0.1, 0.11, 0.112]})

val2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'group':g, 'perc': 0.99, 'time':range(1, 11)} 
                                  for g in data1['group'].unique())]).explode('time')

mat = np.arange(75).reshape(3,5,5)


vals = [val1, val2]

data1['cat'] = pd.Categorical(data1['cat'], 
                                        categories=listc, 
                                        ordered=True).codes

for i in range(len(vals)):
    if 'group' in vals[i].columns:
        vals[i] = vals[i].set_index(['time', 'group'])
    else:
        vals[i] = vals[i].set_index(['time'])
 
#nested loop calculation       
calc = {}
for client, cat, amt, start, group in data1.itertuples(name=None, index=False):
    for time in range(start, len(mat)+1):
        if time == start:
            calc[client] = [[amt * mat[time-1, cat, :]]]
        else:
            calc[client].append([calc[client][-1][-1] @ mat[time-1]])
                
        for valcal in vals:
            if isinstance(valcal.index, pd.MultiIndex):
                value = valcal.loc[(time, group)].iat[0]
            else:
                value = valcal.loc[time].iat[0]
            calc[client][-1].append(value * calc[client][-1][-1])
```

output:

```
{'x1': [[array([30000, 31000, 32000, 33000, 34000]), 
   array([3300., 3410., 3520., 3630., 3740.]),
   array([3267. , 3375.9, 3484.8, 3593.7, 3702.6])],
  [array([1050885., 1068309., 1085733., 1103157., 1120581.]), #how is this line calculated?
   array([117699.12 , 119650.608, 121602.096, 123553.584, 125505.072]),
   array([116522.1288 , 118454.10192, 120386.07504, 122318.04816,
          124250.02128])]],
 'x2': [[array([21000, 21300, 21600, 21900, 22200]),
   array([2352. , 2385.6, 2419.2, 2452.8, 2486.4]),
   array([2328.48 , 2361.744, 2395.008, 2428.272, 2461.536])]]}
```

what I need the calc for this line to be is:
`[array([1050885., 1068309., 1085733., 1103157., 1120581.])`

it should take `array([3267. , 3375.9, 3484.8, 3593.7, 3702.6])]` multiplied by mat at time 3, how can I get it to do this?

Comment: I don't know where your got that code, but it's not a state-of-the-art way to use pandas, it would likely be rewritten in a much more concise and efficient vectorial way. My advice, check the requirements for the function and recode it from scratch…

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.